# Missing Icons in 11.10 upgrade

Tags: 11.10, upgrade, icons

After upgrading to 11.10 from 11.04 (I think), some of the icons such as the folder icons in Nautalus are replaced with the generic file icon... This makes it hard to navigate.

Is there any easy way to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried changing the theme in appearance System Settings?

Comment: That didn't help, most icons are either the generic file one, or blank.

Comment: Can you post a pastebin link of the output of `ls /usr/share/icons -R`

Comment: Here's some of the output, it was too long to post everything. Note how some folders are empty. http://pastie.org/2775673

Comment: Thats normal, it just means some icons are not available in all sizes, which theme are you using?

Comment: Tried all of the defaults, the problem happened after the upgrade, so clearly something had permission errors or such.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seem like you've got some missing them icons. Try running

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install humanity-icon-theme gnome-icon-theme
```

If your icons are still not fixed you can also try

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install gnome-icon-theme-full
```

You can also try removing/moving `~/.icons`

Comment: I reinstalled the first two, but it didn't change the number of files in /usr/share/icons.  Then I installed gnome-icon-theme-full, logged out and back in, and the problem was fixed.  I doubt gnome-icon-theme-full is needed, but installing it triggered whatever needed to be done to get the icons to appear.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem on two of my computers.  After a great deal of time - even a conplete re-install, I discovered that it was a simple configuration setting.  Here is what worked for me:

System Settings / Appearance / Select Radiance theme

All my icons magically re-appeared.

Comment: swapping themes and then back worked for me